# Netbeans: Declaring Variables in Comments does not work

Tags: php, netbeans

..when the variable is a $this->member.

For instance:

/* @var $this->myObject MyClass */

does not work.

/* @var $foo SomeOtherClass */

works.

Any special coding needed for $this members?

(See also http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/php-variables-screencast.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do typehinting on class variables, but you'll have to do that where they are defined. Per example:

```
<?php
class Foo { 
    function bar( ) {
        return 'foo-bar';
    }
}

class Bar {
    /**
     * Contains a Foo.
     * @var Foo
     */
     protected $foo;

     public function foobar( ) {
         return $this->foo; /** Here, you'd get autocompletion when you add ->. */
     }
}
```

Comment: Great. Could not find this in the Netbeans documentation. Thx. :)